# Как в Grid CSS сделать в одной колонке 3 ряда, а в другой два?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, css-grid

Как сделать так что бы в одной колонке были 3 грид блока друг за другом, а во второй всего лишь два. Сайт выгрузил на хостинг sizovleonid.ru. Хочу, чтобы кнопки были прижаты к тексту и шли 3 блоком, а у второго блока(текста) высоту равную его содержимому.

P.S: Я только учусь, проявите терпение)

```css
.header {
        display:grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
        column-gap: 17%;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="header">
                    <div class="logo">
                        <img src="Img/header/Lucid.png" alt="Logo">
                    </div>
                    <div class="menu-links">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Номе</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Fetures</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Testimonials</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Priching</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="main-text">
                        <h3 class="mini-headline" >introducing lucid theme</h3>
                        <h1>Carefully crafted and beautiful landing page</h1>
                        <p>Etiam ullamcorper et turpis eget hendrerit. Praesent varius risus mi, at elementum magna ultricies accumsan. Cras venenatis lacus sed dolor placerat tempus. Morbi blandit at neque ut imperdiet.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="button">
                        <button class="btn-active">Download now</button>
                        <button class="btn-close">Viev features</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="main-img">
                        <img src="Img/header/devices_kopia.png" alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Добавляй CSS код, чтоб было видно что там у тебя))

Comment: Есть две колонки (Левая и правая по 1fr), в первой колонке у нас logo, main-text, button. В правой колонке у нас menu-links и main-img(На хостинге видно нагляднее если нужно) Дак вот в первой колонке второй строкой идёт main-text я хочу что бы этот блок занимал ровно столько сколько есть его содержимое, таким образом button встанет прям под text-main

Comment: Зачем использовать грид там, где он не нужен? Впрочем, сделать можно.